# I need to parse through a dictionary and update its value

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a problem statement in which I have to read a JSON file. The JSON file when converted to the dictionary using json.loads() has 12 keys.

One of the key('body') has the value which is of type string. When converting this string again to dictionary using json.loads() results in a list of dictionaries. The length of this list of dictionaries is 1000 while each dictionary within has a length of 24.

I need to increase the number of dictionaries so that my list of dictionaries has a new length of 2000. Each dictionary within has a length of 24 has a key('id') that needs to be unique.

Now, this is my code snippet where I'm trying to update the value of the dictionary if my key value is 'id':

```
val = 1
    
    for each_dict in list_of_dictionary:
        for k,v in each_dict.items():
            if k == 'id':
                v = val
                print("value is ",v)
                val = val+1
                
O/P
value is 1
value is 2 
and so on...
```

Now, when I am trying to view the updated value again, I can see the previous values only.
This is the code snippet:

```
for each_dict in list_of_dictionary:
        for k,v in each_dict.items():
            if k == 'id':
                print("value is ",v)
                
                
O/P
value is 11123
value is 11128
and so on...
```

Whereas I want the output as above since I have updated the values already.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I need to increase the number of dictionaries so that my list of dictionaries has a new length of 2000. Now, each dictionary with has a length of 24 has a key('id') that needs to be unique."  How do you go from 1000 to 2000?  Do you simply want to duplicate each of the original 1000?  What format do you want the keys?

Comment: Yes i want to duplicate the data but if I just copy paste manually, the key('id')  value won't be unique. The key value is of type integer

Comment: Dictionary keys must be unique!!!! Do you want to preserve the original key and add a second key which is just an integer, or do you want to alter the original key by appending an integer?

Comment: I wanted to alter the value of the key('id') here so that I could copy-paste the old set of key-value pairs here. Doing this would help me increase the length of dictionaries while my value of the key('id') would also be unique throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Actually in the first for-in loop, I realized that I forgot to update the dictionary and that's why in the second loop, I couldn't see the updated data. So the updated code for the first for loop would be :

```
val = 1 
for each_dict in list_of_dictionary: 
    for k,v in each_dict.items(): 
        if k == 'id': 
            temp = {k, val} 
            each_dict.update(temp)
            val = val+1
```

Now I'm able to see the updated data in the second loop.